# How can I patch a 5-1/2” hole in plywood?

Tags: hole-repair

I need to patch a 5-1/2” hole in plywood. I will be drilling another 5-1/2” hole. What is the best way to patch the old hole? Using the new circle from drilling the new hole? I’m sure it will be a hair smaller than 5-1/2” so how can I get it to hold in the old hole?

The hole is in the bottom of a pinball cabinet, and is used for a subwoofer. The current location does not work for the parts that I have so I need to drill a new hole and yes it needs to be flush. It is 3/4” birch plywood.

Comment: Do both surfaces need to be flush, or can you use a backing piece to screw to the inside and outside of the hole?

Comment: If for some reason you cannot use wood backer (such as this plywood is flush against another surface or member), there are steel clips that hold in a patch like the new 5-1/2" piece. Normally used for drywall but would work for plywood too. Then fill with wood filler or expoxy. Google drywall patch clips.

Comment: A solution I've seen on both doors and shower walls is a "decorative" metal plate that covers the old hole while having an opening for the new one.

Comment: How close is the new hole to the old hole going to be? Will they overlap? Will they be in totally different parts of the cabinet? Since this will be on the bottom, it doesn't have to be pretty, so darn near anything should do the trick. Unless, of course, you're doing a concourse level restoration on a historic console...

Answer (score 1):

Take a piece of furring strip and screw it to the back of your new circle across the middle. Have the edges extend about an inch on each side. Place the new circle from the inside of the cabinet and screw the extended edges into the cabinet. Then fill the thin crack with wood filler.

Comment: I'd just use silicone caulk to close the gap considering the location and function of the panel, but yeah.